# Facebook Graph API: likes and shares fields always equal

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Consider the following Graph API requests information about some URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.cnn.com/2016/09/05/asia/north-korea-ballistic-missiles/index.html&fields=og_object%7Bengagement%7Bcount%7D%7D%2Cshare&access_token=<your_access_token>
```

Here's the result for this request:

```
{
   "og_object": {
      "engagement": {
         "count": 1319
      },
      "id": "1374876959196857"
   },
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 1319
   },
   "id": "http://www.cnn.com/2016/09/05/asia/north-korea-ballistic-missiles/index.html"
}
```

You can see that `og_object.engagement.count` = 1319 and so is `share.share_count`!
That's not a coincidence as it happens for every URL.

This number (1319 in our case) is actually the likes count, so the `share.share_count` is obviously wrong.

Why is that and how to get the real shares count?

Thanks